# WebRequest gets a TaskCanceledException in WinHttpGetProxyForUrl()

Tags: c#

I use JsonHttpClient for webrequests. Some requests go well (sometimes not the first), then I eventually get a TaskCanceledException on a request.
The requests all go to a server in the local network.
My PC is AMD Ryzen with Win7 64bit and VS2017.

After debugging the code, it looks like System.Net.WinHttpWebProxyFinder.WinHttpGetProxyForUrl hangs for 2 minutes, then the exception occurs. No request is started (checked with Wireshark).

[Debug VS2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePw9c.png)
At the next query after the exception, the function will run normally.

If I start a query when the problem occurs with another program (curl, browser), my program will be unblocked and the queries will work again.

The code to call the requests looks like this, is in a dll, and is called from NUnit3 (NUnit3TestAdapter v3.10.0) tests with different endpoints.
The commented-out code was an attempt for each request to create a new client, but did not change the behavior.

```cs
public string PostRsRest(string url, string content = "")
{
    try
    {
        //testClient = new JsonHttpClient($"http://{Ip}:{Port}");
        //testClient.GetHttpClient().Timeout = new TimeSpan(TimeOut);
        var response = testClient.Post<string>(url, content);
        RestLogger.Info("post request for: " + url + " returns: " + response);
        //testClient.Dispose();
        return response;
    }
    catch (WebException webException)
    {
        RestLogger.Error("Post error, url: " + url + "  message: " + webException.Message);
        return webException.Message;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException reqException)
    {
        RestLogger.Error("Post error, url: " + url + "  message: " + reqException.Message);
        return reqException.Message;
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException taskCexception)
    {
        RestLogger.Error("Post error, url: " + url + "  message: " + taskCexception.Message);
        if (taskCexception.InnerException != null)
        {
            RestLogger.Error("Post error, url: " + url + "  meassage: " + taskCexception.InnerException.Message);
        }
        return taskCexception.Message;
    }
}
```

Trials with the .Net HttpClient show no change. Just the same with .Net 4.7.1.
How can I avoid the exception?